# Understanding disassembly of Dalvik code?

Tags: java, android, reverse-engineering, disassembly, dalvik

I am playing around with [smali and baksmali](http://code.google.com/p/smali/) on a small Hello World Android application I have written. My source code is:

```
package com.hello;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;

public class Main extends Activity {
    /** Called when the activity is first created. */
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);
    }
}
```

which was then disassembled to:

```
.class public Lcom/hello/Main;
.super Landroid/app/Activity;
.source "Main.java"


# direct methods
.method public constructor <init>()V
    .locals 0

    .prologue
    .line 6
    invoke-direct {p0}, Landroid/app/Activity;-><init>()V

    return-void
.end method


# virtual methods
.method public onCreate(Landroid/os/Bundle;)V
    .locals 1
    .parameter "savedInstanceState"

    .prologue
    .line 10
    invoke-super {p0, p1}, Landroid/app/Activity;->onCreate(Landroid/os/Bundle;)V

    .line 11
    const/high16 v0, 0x7f03

    invoke-virtual {p0, v0}, Lcom/hello/Main;->setContentView(I)V

    .line 12
    return-void
.end method
```

I understand that this is some kind of Intermediate Representation but am not sure what it is. As I understand there must be some specification on how to understand this representation but am unable to figure out how to search for it. So given an apk file, can someone explain in layman terms on how the [Dalvik opcode specification](http://pallergabor.uw.hu/androidblog/dalvik_opcodes.html) is used to arrive at this representation? My current understanding is this:

- Given an APK, I could extract the
  AndroidManifest.xml in a Binary XML
  format and use a tool such as
  [axml2xml.pl](http://code.google.com/p/android-random/source/browse/trunk/axml2xml/axml2xml.pl) to get a "textual"
  version of the manifest that is not
  complete OR I could use the
  [apktool](http://code.google.com/p/android-apktool/) to get a more readable
  form. But I am still not sure what
  specification they are using to
  convert the binary XML into text.
- The
  disassemblers are **somehow** utilizing
  the Dalvil opcode specification to
  read the dex files and convert it
  into the above representation.

Any information (perhaps with some simple examples) on the above two steps would help me in a great way in getting the concepts right.

**Update 1 (posted after the reply from Chris):**

So essentially, I would do the following to arrive at the Dalvik bytecode:

- Take an apk and extract it to get the classes.dex files.
- Then the disassembler reads the classes.dex file and determines all the classes present in the apk. Can you provide me some information on how this is done? Does it parse the file in hex mode and lookup the Dalvik specification and then resolve appropriately? Or is something else happening? For instance, when I used hexdump on classes.dex, it gave me something like this:

  64 65 78 0a 30 33 ...

Are these now used for Opcode lookups?

- Assuming that the tool was able to separate the incoming bytecode into separate classes, it then continues to scan the hex codes from the classes.dex file and uses the Davlik specification to output the appropriate Opcode name from the table?

Actually, in short, I am interested in knowing how all this "magic" is done. So for instance, if I were to learn to write this tool, what is the high-level roadmap I should follow?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

What you're looking at is the davlik bytecode.  Java code is translated to Dalvik bytecode by the dx tool. The manifest is a separate issue which I'll get to in a minute.  Effectively, when you compile your Android application, the dx tool converts your Java code into bytecode (the same way that javac converts Java to Java bytecode for a standard JVM application) using the 256 dalvik opcodes.

For example, `invoke-super` is an opcode that instructs the dvm (dalvik virtual machine) to invoke a method on the super class.  Similarly, `invoke-interface` instructs the dvm to invoke an interface method.

So you can see that

```
super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
```

translates to

```
invoke-super {p0, p1}, Landroid/app/Activity;->onCreate(Landroid/os/Bundle;)
```

In this case, `invoke-super` takes two parameters, the `{p0,p1` group and the `Landroid/app/Activity;->onCreate(Landroid/os/Bundle;)` parameter which is the method specification which it uses to look up and resolve the method if necessary.

Then there's the `invoke-direct` call in the constructor area.

```
invoke-direct {p0}, Landroid/app/Activity;-><init>()V
```

Every class has an `init` method that is used to initialize the class's data members, also known as the constructor.  When you construct a class, the virtual machine must also call the constructor of the superclass.  This explains why the constructor for your class calls the `Activity` constructor.

With regards to the manifest, what happens (this is all in the Dalvik specs if you check out the source code) is that the compiler (that generates the apk file) converts the manifest to a more compressed format (binary xml) for the purposes of saving space.  The manifest doesn't have anything to do with the code you posted, it more instructs the dvm on how to process the application is a whole with regards to `Activities`, `Services`, etc.  What you've posted is what actually gets executed.

That's a high-level answer to your question.  If you need more, let me know and I'll do my best.

**Edit** You're basically right.  The decompiler reads the binary data as a byte stream from the dex file.  It has an understanding of what the format should be and is able to pull out information like constants, classes, etc.  With regards to the opcodes, that's exactly what it does.  It understand what the byte value for each opcode is (or how it's represented in the dex file) and is able to convert that into a human-readable string.  If you were going to implement this, aside from understanding the general basics of compilers, I would start with a deep understanding of the structure of a dex file.  From there, you would need to construct a table that matches opcode values with the human-readable string.  With that information and some additional information regarding string constants, etc. you could construct a text-file representation of the compiled class.  Does that make sense?

Comment: +1 Thank you for your time. The code that I posted in my question no makes sense to me. I updated my question with my current understanding after seeing your response. Could you please take a look at it? As a clarification regarding the Manifest file, so is it possible to recover the original xml file from the compressed form? I mean, are these actually giving me the original xml file? In this particular case, it did but is this always true?

Comment: @Legend, I've updated my answer to reflect your updates.  With regards to the manifest file, I'm not sure.  I'm almost positive it will be functionally the same.  That is, the result will be equivalent (as far as the device is concerned) to the original, but it might not have the same whitespace characters, etc.

Comment: Thank you very much for the detailed explanation. Accepted as answer. As a last note, would you happen to know of any tutorials that explain this concept with an example? It doesn't have to be Dalvik specific (could be Java byte code related as well). I just want to see this in action being performed on some byte code i.e. from byte code to a readable format.

Comment: @Legend, To be honest with you, the process is very similar to the process of compilation in general.  Bytecode is really just a specific form of machine language.  For instance, you could build a VM for C++ that reads x86 machine language and executes it on some other system, or even on an x86 system.  To start, I would suggest reading about compilers in general but I'll see if I can find you something specific to java.  Alternatively, if you're feeling really ambitious, the dx tool is open source and part of the android repository...

Comment: Thank you once again. Any references specific to Java would be great as well when you find some time but as of now, I'm off to get the Android source. I'll poke around a little bit :)

Answer (score 3):

The opcode specification only describes the instructions. The [dex file format](http://www.netmite.com/android/mydroid/dalvik/docs/dex-format.html) is more than that - it contains all the metadata needed for the Dalvik VM (and the disassembler) to interpret the file - strings, classes, types, methods and so on. See also the [official opcode spec](http://www.netmite.com/android/mydroid/dalvik/docs/dalvik-bytecode.html), it's more complete and verbose than the one you linked.

`<plug>`BTW, the next version of [IDA Pro](http://www.hex-rays.com/idapro/) will support disassembly of .dex files`</plug>`

Comment: That looks like a more complete page. Thanks! IDAPro seems to be awesome but commercial :( Looks like only the older versions are available for free.

Comment: Nothing on netmite.com is "official".  The official versions are in the Android source tree, e.g. http://android.git.kernel.org/?p=platform/dalvik.git;a=tree;f=docs;h=7045c2e00b823918a8387187ca171d4c68936080;hb=HEAD .  (OTOH, the netmite copy is easier to read than the one in the git repository because the CSS page is present.)